# jAuery selection button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table like this

[image: Table]

And I need do selection 7 buttons and more. with min and max.

Like type="checkbox" or type="radio" but with type="button" (to do style button with css/css3)

```
<div class="button">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="1" value="01" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="2" value="02" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="3" value="03" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="4" value="04" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="5" value="05" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="6" value="06" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="7" value="07" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="8" value="08" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="9" value="09" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="10" value="10" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="11" value="11" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="12" value="12" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="13" value="13" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="14" value="14" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="15" value="15" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="16" value="16" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="17" value="17" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="18" value="18" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="19" value="19" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="20" value="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="21" value="21" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="22" value="22" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="23" value="23" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="24" value="24" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="25" value="25" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="26" value="26" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="27" value="27" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="28" value="28" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="29" value="29" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="30" value="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="31" value="31" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="32" value="32" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="33" value="33" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="34" value="34" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="35" value="35" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="36" value="36" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="37" value="37" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="38" value="38" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="39" value="39" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="40" value="40" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="41" value="41" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="42" value="42" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="43" value="43" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="44" value="44" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="45" value="45" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="46" value="46" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="47" value="47" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="48" value="48" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="49" value="49" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="50" value="50" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="51" value="51" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="52" value="52" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="53" value="53" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="54" value="54" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="55" value="55" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="56" value="56" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="57" value="57" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="58" value="58" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="59" value="59" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="60" value="60" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="61" value="61" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="62" value="62" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="63" value="63" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="64" value="64" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="65" value="65" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="66" value="66" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="67" value="67" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="68" value="68" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="69" value="69" />
                <input type="button" id="button1" name="70" value="70" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/n2RAh/ (now i can select only one)

Comment: Why not style radio or checkboxes instead, provides the same functionality. Also having more than one element with the same id usually breaks something on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with the inputs, use JavaScript not CSS.

With jQuery, you can add "focus" class.

```
$(".button input[type=button]").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("focus"); 
});

$("#HS").click(function () { // Add an input
  var array = []
  $(".button input[type=button].focus").each(function () {
    array.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(array.join(", "));
});
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/Dp8tR/

### Old solution :

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("focus"); 
});
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/TTL8d/

Comment: thants. this is exactly what i need ))) Can i give to this focus (max selection) ?

Comment: Yes, actually I made this. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `checkbox` and style them as you feel like (`button`). And also style the `:checked` state.

Answer (score 1):

add class to all buttons for example: "markble".
jQuery:

```
$( ".markble" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "activ-now" );
});
```

CSS:

```
.activ-now {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  background: yellow;
}
```

you can detect all selected by class "activ-now".

### demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n2RAh/3/